# FCM push notifications for 10000 users

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notifications to over 10000 users using FCM through a scheduled job using Java. 
Since FCM do have limitations of 500 tokens in sending notifications to multiple devices , how can we implement that

Comment: This kind of questions don't follow the stackoverflow spirit. There is not an specific question

Comment: There is no precise question here.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send a message to more tokens than the FCM API allows in a single call, you will have to call the FCM API multiple times.

So with 10,000 tokens and a maximum of 500 tokens per API call, you'll have to make at least 20 calls.

The FCM API is robust enough (and in fact designed/implemented) to handle this number of calls.

Comment: One thing to note: You can make use of the Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP protocol
to send to up to 1,000 tokens at once: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref